# Windows service for windows mobile

Tags: windows-mobile, compact-framework

Can we write a windows service for windows mobile (Compact framework) which shall be activated on device start. Can you pl. provide link to resource / sample code for the same.

Thanks.

Comment: "Can you pl. provide link to resource / sample code for the same" -> Can't you Google it?

Comment: @balexandre I looked a while back and drew so many blanks - This is a classic case of not knowing a detailed enough search term to filter down the results

Answer (score 2):

You can't use Compact Framework for the development of a windows service. This is an [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446909.aspx) in MSDN about writing services for Windows CE.

For a regular application, this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433325/running-background-services-on-a-pocketpc) has some ideas on how you can make it to automatically launch on start up.

Answer (score 2):

There is a CodePlex project that you can check out that is likely going to be your best best for creating a Windows Server on a windows mobile device.

And there is a related blog article you can check out for more details.

[Managed Services for Windows Mobile](http://www.codeplex.com/managedserviceswm)

[Services for Windows Mobile in managed code](http://bansky.net/blog/2008/04/services-for-windows-mobile-in-managed-code/)