# C# Windows CE 5.0 error: Can't find entry point ExitWindowsEx in PInvoke DLL coredll

Tags: c#, compact-framework, windows-ce

I need to programatically shutdown a Windows CE 5.0 tablet using Microsoft.NET SDK CompactFramework v2.0. I tried using the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/207542/how-can-i-shutdown-a-windows-mobile-device-programatically) but got the error message

> Can't find entry point ExitWindowsEx
>   in PInvoke DLL coredll

Is there a way to add ExitWindowsEx to my build?
Do I need a different coredll?

```
[Flags]
public enum ExitFlags
{
    Reboot = 0x02,
    PowerOff = 0x08
}
[DllImport("coredll")]
public static extern int ExitWindowsEx(ExitFlags flags, int reserved);
private static void buttonShutdown_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ExitWindowsEx(ExitFlags.PowerOff, 0);
}
private static void buttonRestart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ExitWindowsEx(ExitFlags.Reboot, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't  just swap out coredll.dll, it's part of the OS.  To change coredll, you need an entirely new OS.

That said, it's not clear that you need one.  `ExitWindowsEx` is likely not the call you want to be making (it's not supported in CE), but instead you probably should be calling [`KernelIoControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms886729.aspx) with IOCTL_HAL_REBOOT for a soft reset.

There really is no standard "power off" so if you truly need to shut down power, check with your OEM. There is, however, a device Suspend mode (assuming it's in your specific OS).  Suspend can be gotten at programmatically by P/Invoking [`GwesPowerOffSystem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms902923.aspx) or post a VK_OFF key to the keyboard stream.